# How to insert data in two Joined table queries (VIEW)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. One table has 12 values and other table is empty. i have joined both tables and show all values in column of Table A and Also column of B. Now showing Table A values i have to insert data in same view but in EVENT_DESC, when i edit this it allows me to edit SYMP_TYPES Column but not EVENT_DESC. How i can edit event_desc?

[image]

```
select a.rowid, a.SYMP_TYPES,e.event_desc
from MEDICAL_SYMPOTYMS_DETAILS a, event_transactions e
where a.SYMP_ID=1
and e.event_master_id(+)=a.symp_id
```

Comment: unrelated MySQL tag removed MySQL does not support Oracle database " LEFT/RIGHT" join `(+)` operator extension on the old ANSI/ISO SQL 86 standard comma join syntax..

Comment: ... also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

If EVENT_DESC is the primary key of table B you won't be able to edit it through a view

Comment: No event_desc is not primary key

Comment: Can you provide table structures?